# Why does pip install from github fail when pip install -e succeeds?

Tags: python, pip, conda

There's a git repo at https://github.com/Ivancic91/LammpsIO that I can install in "editable" mode by cloning and running `pip install -e /path/to/LammpsIO`. When I do this, I'm able to run `import LammpsIO` successfully in python.

However, when I pip install directly from github with `pip install git+https://github.com/Ivancic91/LammpsIO.git` I run into problems. The actual `pip install` command looks successful with the usual success messages:

```
Successfully built LammpsIO
Installing collected packages: LammpsIO
Successfully installed LammpsIO-0.0.1
```

But when I try to import LammpsIO, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LammpsIO'`.

I thought this might be some sort of path error, but `which pip` and `which python` both point to the same conda environment folder.

Here are a couple more outputs in case anyone needs them.

After `pip install git+...`:

1. `conda list` returns:

krb5                      1.16.3            h24a3359_1000    conda-forge
lammpsio                  0.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
libcurl                   7.64.0               h76de61e_0    conda-forge

2. `pip list` returns:

kiwisolver               1.0.1
LammpsIO                 0.0.1
MarkupSafe               1.1.0

After `pip install -e ...`:

1. `conda list` returns:

krb5                      1.16.3            h24a3359_1000    conda-forge
lammpsio                  0.0.1                     dev_0       libcurl                   7.64.0               h76de61e_0    conda-forge

2. `pip list` returns:

kiwisolver               1.0.1
LammpsIO                 0.0.1      /path/to/LammpsIO/src
MarkupSafe               1.1.0

I'm guessing this has to do with the unorthodox structure of LammpsIO, whose `setup.py` file contains:

```
package_dir = {'': 'src'},
packages = find_packages(where='src'),
```

but I'm surprised that pip install from github fails where `pip install -e /path` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning seems sound here. I'd think that what you're trying to would work. I created a new virtualenv and tried the github install myself. I then looked in site-packages. What I see is strange. There's a 'LammpsIO-0.0.1.dist-info' directory containing basic metadata, but no Lammps package itself. I did the find 'find . -iname "*mmps*"' in site-packages, and only got that info directory. So it seems like the package didn't actually install. - LammpsIO does show up when I do "pip list".

If you "install" the package by download a zip and doing "pip install [zip]", you get the same output from pip and end up with the same problem. So it has nothing to do with installing directly from github. It has to do with actually installing the package vs just linking its source into your enviroment .

My guess is that the Lammps installer is just broken - Since '-e' doesn't install anything, but just creates a link, that would explain why it works but a regular install does not.

Comment: For future me or future anyone else, fixing the project structure and setup.py file took care of the problem. [This pull request](https://github.com/Ivancic91/LammpsIO/pull/4) did the trick.

Comment: Ha!  I love it!  You fixed the problem with the installer.  That's super cool.  It both solves your issue, and let's me know that I was actually correct in my diagnosis.  I'm impressed. I don't think I'd have ventured to fix someone else's work like that. 
I wasn't sure if I'd missed something somehow and the installer wasn't in fact broken.  We make a great team!

Comment: Thanks, but to be fair, even though this is someone else's package, I was the one that made the pull request to add the original broken installer :) I just fixed my own broken work

Comment: Oh...Ooops! - Well, then glad I could assist you in fixing your pull request, lol.  I never had any idea I was talking about your work when I said the installer was broken.  What I said about taking the initiative still holds true :)